# Build-in external binary embedded in custom Terraform provider

Tags: go, terraform

I'm currently creating private Terraform provider that is required to make calls to external binary (PEX file) via `exec.Command`

If make very short example:

```
func resourceCreate(d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) error {
   ...
   cmd := exec.Command("./custom-pex-file", arg...)
   ...
}
```

I'm wondering what is correct and easy way to build-in this custom PEX file in final binary that would be compiled by go compiler.

Comment: In order for the OS to execute the binary, it needs to be in the filesystem. Are you just looking to store the binary until runtime? There are a ton of packages for embedding assets in your binary.

Comment: I found a couple to store static assets in go binary. However, I'm new to Go, so don't quite understand how can I call that binary from inside go code.

Comment: That's not really a go specific issue, you ned to put the binary somewhere in the filesystem so it can be executed.